# Type error in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, aws-appsync

I am new to react-native and aws appsync,graphql.we are trying to implement functionality in which we will be having a send button so as soon as we hit the send button the text should appear on the screen.The thing is we have achieved it but as soon as we hit it we are getting error saying

> Type error
>   we have no clue why this error is caused
>
> [Type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnroE.png)
>
> [Warning 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kQpo.png)
>
> [Warning 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySUbP.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import ChatView from './ChatView';
//import onCreatePostMessage from './query/onCreatePostMessage';

export default class ChatHistory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
}

componentWillMount() {
     this.props.onCreatePostMessage();
}

render() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text>ChatHistory</Text>
              <FlatList data={[].concat(this.props.chats).sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.localeCompare(b.createdAt))} 
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ChatView chat={item}/>}
                ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
                onContentSizeChange={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
                onLayout={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})} />
          </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 20
    }
});
```

Please help me resolve this issue!!.Thanks

Comment: looks like createdAt is a date and localeCompare is a method of string class. Can you please try it?

Comment: Thanks for your time. **createdAt: new Date().toISOString()** that is what i have given to my input text

Comment: does that work now?

Comment: yes @Vishal but the thing is i feel like i have an error with id let me explain you. In the aws dynamodb i have generated an autoid for the field id using util package provided in graphql.But in my code i have given the createdAt value for the id field.Do we have Any method so that we can map the id field value in the backend to the id field in the front end.I might be wrong Please correct me